# What do the asterisks in Lisp documentation templates mean?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, ebnf

For example:

```
* (describe 'do)
```

...

```
  Documentation:
    DO ({(Var [Init] [Step])}*) (Test Exit-Form*) Declaration* Form*
```

What do the stars in this documentation template mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` is the *repeat zero or more times* symbol in BNF-like notations.

Thus

```
FOO Form*
```

means that the preceeding element can be repeated zero or more times:

```
(foo form-1 ... form-n)  ; zero or more forms
```

Also, where { and } is a grouping syntax:

```
FOO ({(Form-a Form-a)}*)
```

means

```
(foo ((form-1-a form-1-b)              ; zero or more
      ...
      (form-n-a form-n-b)))
```

Comment: A link to the section [1.4.1.2 of the CLHS](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/01_dab.htm) seems apropos.

Comment: @PuercoPop Legend says that only the warrior who already knows what the `*` already means can find 1.4.1.2 of the CLHS.